# How do you change a CSS link document with PHP if/else? Displays no error message

Tags: php, css, if-statement

Trying to set up templates on a site I am working on, and I want to change the linked stylesheet document instead of using PHP within the CSS. Would this be possible? Thanks.

```
<?php

    require 'includes/templates.php';

    if($_COOKIE['template'] == $blocky) {

        echo "<link rel="stylesheet" href="/testpages/css/blocky.css">";

    }

    else {

        echo "<link rel="stylesheet" href="/testpages/css/default.css">";

    }

?>
```

Comment: You have to escape your quotes in the string: `echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/testpages/css/blocky.css\">";` so that it doesn't think that that is the end of the string.  Or you can use single quotes `'` instead for it: `echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/testpages/css/blocky.css">'`

Answer (score 2):

Yes that would possible, but make sure to escape your quotes

```
 <?php
    require 'includes/templates.php';

     if($_COOKIE['template'] == $blocky) {

         echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/testpages/css/blocky.css\">";

     }

     else {

         echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/testpages/css/default.css\">";

     }

 ?>
```